# Show that $A_5$ (alternating group of degree $n$) has $24$ elements of order $5$, $20$ elements of order $3$, and $15$ elements of order $2$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Show that $A_5$ (alternating group of degree $n$) has $24$ elements of order $5$, $20$ elements of order $3$, and $15$ elements of order $2$.

I'm a little confused on this.  Wouldn't there be $5!$ elements of order $5$ since any element of order $5$ is of the form $(abcde)$?

Comment: What Morgan Rodgers said. Another way to think about this is to recall that $A_5$ has $|S_5|/2=60$ elements altogether, and $60<5!$, so your calculation must be off somehow. Mind you, many learners have fallen into this trap of forgetting that the cycle presentation of a permutation is not unique in this sense. So don't worry too much!

Comment: You may find the Wikipedia article on [Icosahedral symmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icosahedral_symmetry) helpful. It has lots of good diagrams, which can give a better feel for the group than just contemplating permutations.

Comment: So since for each $(abcde)$ there are five different ways to write the same cycle representation (each variation starting with $(a...)$ is exactly another variation starting with $b, c, d, \text{ or } e$), the only unique permutations are those that start with an arbitrary first letter $a$, and permute through the remaining four, which is $4! = 24$.  Does that make sense?

Comment: The order of an element of $A_5$ is completely determined by its cycle type, it is actually the $\lcm$ of its cycle type. You know $A_5$ has cycle types 1 (order 1), 3 (order 3), 5 (order 5), and 2-2 (order 2). Now count the number of elements of the corresponding cycle types :)

Comment: Here is another way to think about how many $5$-cycles there are: we have to send $1$ to something in $\{2,3,4,5\}$, giving us our start: $(1\ a\dots)$. We can start this off $4$ different ways. After that, we have to choose what $a$ maps to out of $\{2,3,4,5\} -\{a\}$, which gives us only $3$ choices ($4 - 1 = 3$). So we have $12$ choices for $(1\ a\ b\dots)$, and we cannot map $b$ to $1,a$ or $b$, but we only have two elements left, so $24$ ways to form $(1\ a\ b\ c\dots)$ in which case $c$ must then map to the last element of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ remaining, which then closes the cycle.